# Problems installing Networkit with pip3

Tags: python-3.8, networkit

I am trying to install networkit 6.1 on macOS 10.15.4 with python 3.8.

I have double checked and made sure that I have all the requirements.

`pip3` errors out while `Building wheel for networkit (setup.py)`

Here is what the error message says.  After extensive Googling, I am still not sure what it means.

I would love any insight that might be provided.  Here is the incredibly long error code:

```
pip3 install networkit
Collecting networkit
  Using cached networkit-6.1.tar.gz (2.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from networkit) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from networkit) (1.18.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: networkit
  Building wheel for networkit (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-wheel-bqalgacb
       cwd: /private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/
  Complete output (518 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/simulation.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/sparsification.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/coloring.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/viztasks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/graphio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/plot.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/randomization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/support.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/clique.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/GraphMLIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/linkprediction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/partitioning.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/globals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/scd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/flow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/coarsening.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/algebraic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/distance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/stopwatch.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/matching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/GEXFIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/generators.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/centrality.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/dynamic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/community.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/stats.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/sampling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/workflows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/engineering.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/structures.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/components.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/viz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/correlation.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  copying networkit/nxadapter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  copying networkit/test/test_randomization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  copying networkit/test/test_community.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  copying networkit/test/test_graphio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  copying networkit/test/test_generators.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  copying networkit/test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  copying networkit/test/test_graphtools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  copying networkit/test/test_graph_traversal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  copying networkit/test/test_sparsification.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  copying networkit/test/test_graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  copying networkit/test/test_algorithms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/gephi
  copying networkit/gephi/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/gephi
  copying networkit/gephi/csv.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/gephi
  copying networkit/gephi/pyclient.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/gephi
  copying networkit/gephi/streaming.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/gephi
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
  copying networkit/profiling/plot.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
  copying networkit/profiling/multiprocessing_helper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
  copying networkit/profiling/job.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
  copying networkit/profiling/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
  copying networkit/profiling/stat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
  copying networkit/profiling/profiling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test/extension
  copying networkit/test/extension/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test/extension
  copying networkit/test/extension/test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test/extension
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test/gephi
  copying networkit/test/gephi/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test/gephi
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
  copying networkit/profiling/html/profile.html -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
  copying networkit/profiling/html/profiling.css -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
  copying networkit/profiling/html/measure.html -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
  copying networkit/profiling/html/profiling.js -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
  copying networkit/profiling/html/overlay.html -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/latex
  copying networkit/profiling/latex/measure.tex -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/latex
  copying networkit/profiling/latex/profile.tex -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/latex
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/description
  copying networkit/profiling/description/descriptions.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/description
  running build_ext
  Cython not available, but _NetworKit.cpp provided. Continue build without cythonizing
  initializing NetworKit compilation with: 'cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=c++ -DNETWORKIT_FLATINSTALL=ON -DNETWORKIT_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -DNETWORKIT_PYTHON_SOABI=cpython-38-darwin /private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit'
  -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.3.11030032
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES)
  -- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
  -- Found OpenMP_CXX: -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include (found version "3.1")
  -- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "3.1")
  -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.3.11030032
  -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Performing Test TLX_CXX_HAS_CXX17
  -- Performing Test TLX_CXX_HAS_CXX17 - Success
  -- TLX CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: -Wshadow -Wold-style-cast -std=c++17 -g -W -Wall -Wextra -fPIC  -Wdeprecated
  -- Looking for pthread.h
  -- Looking for pthread.h - found
  -- Looking for pthread_create
  -- Looking for pthread_create - found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE
  -- sphinx-build not found. Disable documentation targets
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/build/build_python
  Build with: 'make install -j4'
  Scanning dependencies of target tlx
  [  1%] Building CXX object extlibs/tlx/tlx/CMakeFiles/tlx.dir/algorithm/parallel_multiway_merge.cpp.o
  [  1%] Building CXX object extlibs/tlx/tlx/CMakeFiles/tlx.dir/backtrace.cpp.o
  [  1%] Building CXX object extlibs/tlx/tlx/CMakeFiles/tlx.dir/die/core.cpp.o
  [  1%] Building CXX object extlibs/tlx/tlx/CMakeFiles/tlx.dir/cmdline_parser.cpp.o
  [  1%] Building CXX object extlibs/tlx/tlx/CMakeFiles/tlx.dir/digest/md5.cpp.o
  [  2%] Building CXX object extlibs/tlx/tlx/CMakeFiles/tlx.dir/digest/sha1.cpp.o
  [  2%] Building CXX object extlibs/tlx/tlx/CMakeFiles/tlx.dir/digest/sha256.cpp.o
  [  2%] Building CXX object extlibs/tlx/tlx/CMakeFiles/tlx.dir/digest/sha512.cpp.o
  [  2%] Building CXX object extlibs/tlx/tlx/CMakeFiles/tlx.dir/logger/core.cpp.o

...edited for brevity....

  [ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/linkprediction/UDegreeIndex.cpp.o
  [ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/linkprediction/VDegreeIndex.cpp.o
  [ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/matching/LocalMaxMatcher.cpp.o
  [ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/matching/Matcher.cpp.o
  [ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/matching/Matching.cpp.o
  [ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/matching/PathGrowingMatcher.cpp.o
  [ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/overlap/HashingOverlapper.cpp.o
  [ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/overlap/Overlapper.cpp.o
  [ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/randomization/Curveball.cpp.o
  [ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/randomization/CurveballGlobalTradeGenerator.cpp.o
  [ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/randomization/CurveballImpl.cpp.o
  [ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/randomization/CurveballUniformTradeGenerator.cpp.o
  [ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/randomization/DegreePreservingShuffle.cpp.o
  [ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/randomization/GlobalCurveball.cpp.o
  [ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/scd/ApproximatePageRank.cpp.o
  clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
  clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
  Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
  clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
  clang: note: diagnostic msg:
  ********************

  PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
  Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
  clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/DegreePreservingShuffle-57cb30.cpp
  clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/DegreePreservingShuffle-57cb30.sh
  clang: note: diagnostic msg: Crash backtrace is located in
  clang: note: diagnostic msg: /Users/derycpainter/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/clang_<YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS>_<hostname>.crash
  clang: note: diagnostic msg: (choose the .crash file that corresponds to your crash)
  clang: note: diagnostic msg:

  ********************
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/randomization/DegreePreservingShuffle.cpp.o] Error 254
  make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/all] Error 2
  make: *** [all] Error 2
  Build tool returned an error, exiting setup.py
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for networkit
  Running setup.py clean for networkit
Failed to build networkit
Installing collected packages: networkit
    Running setup.py install for networkit ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-record-f2ad9aq9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/derycpainter/Library/Python/3.8/include/python3.8/networkit
         cwd: /private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/
    Complete output (123 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/simulation.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/sparsification.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/coloring.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/viztasks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/graphio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/plot.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/randomization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/support.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/clique.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/GraphMLIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/linkprediction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/partitioning.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/globals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/scd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/flow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/coarsening.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/algebraic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/distance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/stopwatch.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/matching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/GEXFIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/generators.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/centrality.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/dynamic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/community.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/stats.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/sampling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/workflows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/engineering.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/structures.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/components.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/viz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/correlation.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    copying networkit/nxadapter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    copying networkit/test/test_randomization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    copying networkit/test/test_community.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    copying networkit/test/test_graphio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    copying networkit/test/test_generators.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    copying networkit/test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    copying networkit/test/test_graphtools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    copying networkit/test/test_graph_traversal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    copying networkit/test/test_sparsification.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    copying networkit/test/test_graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    copying networkit/test/test_algorithms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/gephi
    copying networkit/gephi/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/gephi
    copying networkit/gephi/csv.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/gephi
    copying networkit/gephi/pyclient.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/gephi
    copying networkit/gephi/streaming.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/gephi
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
    copying networkit/profiling/plot.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
    copying networkit/profiling/multiprocessing_helper.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
    copying networkit/profiling/job.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
    copying networkit/profiling/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
    copying networkit/profiling/stat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
    copying networkit/profiling/profiling.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test/extension
    copying networkit/test/extension/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test/extension
    copying networkit/test/extension/test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test/extension
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test/gephi
    copying networkit/test/gephi/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/test/gephi
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
    copying networkit/profiling/html/profile.html -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
    copying networkit/profiling/html/profiling.css -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
    copying networkit/profiling/html/measure.html -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
    copying networkit/profiling/html/profiling.js -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
    copying networkit/profiling/html/overlay.html -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/html
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/latex
    copying networkit/profiling/latex/measure.tex -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/latex
    copying networkit/profiling/latex/profile.tex -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/latex
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/description
    copying networkit/profiling/description/descriptions.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/networkit/profiling/description
    running build_ext
    Cython not available, but _NetworKit.cpp provided. Continue build without cythonizing
    initializing NetworKit compilation with: 'cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=c++ -DNETWORKIT_FLATINSTALL=ON -DNETWORKIT_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -DNETWORKIT_PYTHON_SOABI=cpython-38-darwin /private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit'
    -- Found OpenMP_CXX: -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include
    -- Found OpenMP: TRUE
    -- TLX CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: -Wshadow -Wold-style-cast -std=c++17 -g -W -Wall -Wextra -fPIC  -Wdeprecated
    -- sphinx-build not found. Disable documentation targets
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/build/build_python
    Build with: 'make install -j4'
    [ 13%] Built target tlx
    [ 15%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/randomization/DegreePreservingShuffle.cpp.o
    [ 15%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/scd/GCE.cpp.o
    [ 15%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/scd/PageRankNibble.cpp.o
    [ 15%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/scd/SelectiveCommunityDetector.cpp.o
    clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
    clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
    Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
    clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
    [ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/simulation/EpidemicSimulationSEIR.cpp.o
    clang: note: diagnostic msg:
    ********************

    PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
    Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
    clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/DegreePreservingShuffle-264185.cpp
    clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/DegreePreservingShuffle-264185.sh
    clang: note: diagnostic msg: Crash backtrace is located in
    clang: note: diagnostic msg: /Users/derycpainter/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/clang_<YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS>_<hostname>.crash
    clang: note: diagnostic msg: (choose the .crash file that corresponds to your crash)
    clang: note: diagnostic msg:

    ********************
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/networkit/cpp/randomization/DegreePreservingShuffle.cpp.o] Error 254
    make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/networkit.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    Build tool returned an error, exiting setup.py
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-install-khdr64cp/networkit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/gy/2kn7_0x140z14dgv422v38jh0000gn/T/pip-record-f2ad9aq9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/derycpainter/Library/Python/3.8/include/python3.8/networkit Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like that you do not have Cython installed, but the build goes on anyway because _NetworKit.cpp is already there. What happens if you install Cython and try again?

Comment: Thank you for replying.  After reinstalling cython with `pip3 install --force-reinstall cython`, and rerunning `pip3 install networkit` I seem to be getting the same error message:
```Collecting networkit
   Building wheels for collected packages: networkit
   Building wheel for networkit (setup.py) ... error```
...continued...
```Cython not available, but _NetworKit.cpp provided. Continue build without cythonizing```
...continued...
`clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
  clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Unfortunately I could not replicate the same error, but I also failed to install NetworKit from pip (python3.8) due to another error. Even though this is not a proper answer, in this circumstances I'd suggest to build NetworKit from source: ```git clone https://github.com/networkit/networkit --depth=1```, ```cd networkit```, and ```pip3 install -e .``` .